# UWP Controls Property not changing from Async Handlers

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, async-await

In the code below I want to disable the login button after a user successfully logs in. I have tried a dozen "solutions" and not matter what I try the values of the controls properties do not change once I leave the Click Routine. If I remove the "async" code everything works as expected.

```
Private Async Sub ButtonLogin_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ' Login the user and then load data from the mobile app.
    Dim Success As Boolean = False
    If Await AuthenticateAsync() Then
        ' Executing from a non-UI thread with helper method
        Dim returnedFromUIThread As Integer = Await DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(
            Function()
                ' Code to execute on main window's UI thread
                ButtonLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
                ButtonLogin.IsEnabled = False
                Return 1
            End Function)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you please a [mcve]?

Comment: I am happy to submit a complete Client example but could you explain how to post it here. Comments are limited to less characters than the full source code.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiKnn5ue9vJbgaZto5JmbV2kfEkH-g Here is a link to a Visual Studio 2017 UWP Project that shows the issue. It will still need a Facebook App to Logon to and Azure Server Application to work against. All it does is logon and try to Disable the Logon Button after success. I just used the UWP sample ToDo server app that Azure provides as a demo and added the Facebook logon information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is after logging in you return to a different copy of the MainPage and the controls I have been modifying are not the ones being displayed. Before logging on you need to save any control state and any references to controls and then reload everything after the login.